# Given TermDocumentMatrix, How can I convert it to numeric matrix?

Tags: r, term-document-matrix

I have already generated a `termDocumentMatrix` as showed below:

```
> tmm
[[1]]
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 18, terms: 4886)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 11956/75992
Sparsity           : 86%
Maximal term length: 25
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Then I want to convert it to numeric matrix, it shows an error.
The command I use is:

```
matrix<-data.matrix(tmm)
```

Then the *matrix* become a list like this:

```
list(i = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
```

Where did I got wrong?

Comment: What version of `tm` are you using? Did you try just `as.matrix`?

Comment: Actually, taking another look there the `[[1]]` indicates you probably don't have a document term matrix, you have a **list** that has a document term matrix. What about `as.matrix(tmm[[1]])`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
matrix <- as.matrix(inspect(tmm))
```